# SQL query to get count with left join

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why this query returns 0? I want to get a number of messages, that have the folderName 'INBOX'. Messages and Folders tables are connected via FolderID.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Messages AS m \
                     LEFT JOIN Folders AS f \
                     ON m.FolderID = f.FolderID \
                     WHERE f.FolderName = 'INBOX'"
```

I exactly know, that there are messages with this folder ID's. The problem is in sql.

Comment: Determine that there are Folders with a folder name INBOX first SELECT * FROM Folders WHERE FolderName = 'INBOX'

Comment: Your query should also be an INNER JOIN. A LEFT JOIN will return messages whether or not there is a match.

Comment: LEFT and INNER JOINs return the same number now. The problem was in my program that put instead of INBOX "Inbox". How do I compare with case insensitivity?

Comment: You will need an INNER join, see answer below for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Messages AS m 
                 INNER JOIN Folders AS f 
                 ON m.FolderID = f.FolderID 
                 WHERE UPPER(f.FolderName) = 'INBOX'
```

It needs to be an inner join and depending on the case sensitivity of the SQL server set up you may need to think about matching case.